# Where are the latest Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images?

Tags: internet-explorer, testing, cross-browser, virtual-pc

Does anyone know where the latest Internet Explorer Application Compatibility VPC Images are?

These ones expired 1st October 2010

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

**UPDATED : If you're reading Microsoft..**

**This is not the user experience developers want. If it would not be too much trouble could you make new VPC images available as soon as old ones expire. Thank you.**

Comment: They always seem to forget about these until people start shouting for them. It will probably be a couple of weeks before new ones come out.

Comment: hmm. At the moment I can use the IE6 one for an hour at a time.

Comment: Did you try setting the clocks backwards?

Comment: Same as Oded said - somehow these images are not high priority for MS. Instead of setting up your own VM/Windows XP Mode you can use Xenocode's Browsers: http://spoon.net/browsers/ They run very smoothly and they are "real" browsers (compared to Tools like IE Tester, which just use the IE rendering engine and can therefore produce different results than the original browser). Give it a try!

Comment: No i might try setting the clocks backwards

Comment: @Lee The Spoon browsers are free, but they don't come with developer tools, and I haven't found a way to install them (which is a pretty big minus)

Comment: And again, the new images expired without new ones in sight. Thanks MS..

Comment: And once again (Nov 2011) — see http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/18216/has-microsoft-stopped-offering-the-free-internet-explorer-application-compatibil. I’d love to pay for non-expiring versions of these images, as they take up much less hard drive space than a standard XP installation.

Comment: The current ones expired back in Feb 2013. They have a note on the download page that support and new images are located at: http://modern.IE

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks as though they have updated them

From the same page
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyId=21EABB90-958F-4B64-B5F1-73D0A413C8EF&displaylang=en

> Windows XP Images These images were
>   last updated on October 13, 2010, and
>   expire on January 11, 2011.
>
> - IE6-on-XPSP3.exe contains a Windows XP SP3 with IE6 VHD file. Expires January 11, 2011
> - IE7-on-XPSP3.exe contains a Windows XP SP3 with IE7 VHD file. Expires January 11, 2011
> - IE8-on-XPSP3.exe contains a Windows XP SP3 with IE8 VHD file.
>     Expires January 11, 2011

Comment: Updated again to version 4.2 on 5/14/2011

Answer (score 3):

## Modern.ie

Seems you need the Microsoft [Modern.ie](http://dev.modern.ie/tools/vms/) web site.

These images are legal as `modern.ie` is run by Microsoft.

They provide a wide range of various versions of Windows (XP, Vista, 7, 8, & 8.1) combined with various versions of Internet Explorer (6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11). (as of 2015-07)

The downloads are pre-configured, Windows-already-installed, and ready-to-run virtual machine image files for multiple virtualizers ([VirtualBox](https://www.virtualbox.org), [Hyper-V](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyper-V), VMware, VPC, [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/)) running on Windows/Mac/Linux hosts.

[image: screenshot of Modern.ie web site’s Download page]

Answer (score 1):

It seems they have expired agian and as yet I can't find updated versions.   The one I have was set to expire on 4th April and sure enough I can't event get thenm to run for an hour.

I'm really wishing that final 6% of my user base would upgrade from ie6!!!

Comment: New versions are avaialble,  running out 26th July 2012  http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

Answer (score 0):

New versions are available, running out 26th July 2012

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11575

Thanks MS :-)